# Powershell Function Output As Argument Value To Git Command

Tags: git, powershell

How to pass the output of a powershell function as an argument to a command?

I was unsuccessful with what I thought was a very straightforward command:

```
git checkout -b SimplifyName("Test 1")
```

output is an error:

```
fatal: 'Test 1' is not a commit and a branch 'SimplifyName' cannot be created from it
```

where, for the sake of this question,

```
function SimplifyName ([string] $str = "UNDEFINED") {
    $result = $str.Trim().ToLowerInvariant() -replace "[^a-z0-9]+","_"
    Write-Output $result
}
```

From what I understand, anything that follows `-b` is taken as space-delimited string arguments for the `git checkout -b` command.

I am struggling to find a good help resource for this too since I am possibly using incorrect terminology.

Comment: When you say that something didn't work, you have to say _how_ it didn't work. (Remember, we can't see your screen.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I've added the output. I wrongly assumed that I was doing something very stupidly wrong which would be obvious just from the command.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart also, am I using the correct jargon? All my search seem to show me how to use a function within another function. :-/

Comment: I can't test it, but `git checkout -b $(SimplifyName("Test 1"))` may be all you need...

Comment: @JamesC. that is it! Add it as an answer and I'll accept it. Unless someone points out that that command also silently breaks the internet! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$()` is a [subexpression operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx), it means 'evaluate this first, and do it separately as an independent statement'.

Here it's used to evaluate the function and then use the output from it for the `git` command:

```
git checkout -b $(SimplifyName "Test 1")
```

Comment: We don't use parentheses to call a function in PowerShell. It's valid syntax-wise but not correct semantically. It should really be `git checkout -b $(SimplifyName "Test1")`.